# Flask built-in server vs gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

i've just started learning about python web development and i've seen lots of python web projects did in flask that are using as a web server gunicorn and i didn't really understood why? because i've seen that flask comes already with a built-in server.Is it bad to use the "default" web server? or is it more of a flavor? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Flasks built-in web server is great for development but not suitable for production. The Flask documentation talks about this along with the other options including gunicorn. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/index.html